# showDialog in button Listview adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, showdialog

i have a listView like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092158/set-button-onclick-in-listview-android/30092841#30092841)

[image]

i want when i press the delete. it show a dialog like this image

[image]

so when i press YES. it will remove from list.

here's my code..

```
public class customadapter extends BaseAdapter{ 

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist;
Context context;
private Button btnDelete;
private Button btnEdit;
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;

public customadapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist,Context context) {  
    System.out.println("skdjfhksdfjskfjhsdkjfh");
    this.context = context;
    this.oslist = oslist;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    return oslist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return oslist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    System.out.println("oslist oslist = "+oslist);
    System.out.println("oslist 1 = "+oslist);
    System.out.println("oslist size = "+oslist.size());
    System.out.println("oslist oslist = "+oslist.getClass());
    System.out.println("position = "+position);
    System.out.println("convertView = "+convertView);
    System.out.println("parent = "+parent);

    System.out.println("position =  "+position);





    LayoutInflater lif = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = lif.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

    TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.varId);  
    TextView noNota = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.varNoNota);
    TextView senderName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.varSenderName);
    TextView totalAmount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.varTotalAmount);

    id.setText(oslist.get(position).get("id"));
    noNota.setText(oslist.get(position).get("noNota"));
    senderName.setText(oslist.get(position).get("senderName"));
    totalAmount.setText(oslist.get(position).get("totalAmount"));   

    Button btnEdit = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
    Button btnDelete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Edit ditekan!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //I want show YES NO dialog here.           
        }
    });

    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //I want show YES NO dialog here
        }
    });   

    return convertView;
}
```

}

how can i do to create a dialog like that..i tried this code

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
                dialog.setTitle("Title...");

                // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
                ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); //line 115

                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
```

but itsnt success.

i got this error

[image]

Comment: i already update my post...i post log logcat

Comment: what is your `line number 115` in `customadapter` ?

Comment: Maybe, this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10336214/3913366 ...

Comment: also you should use naming conventions like insted of `customadapter` name it `CustomAdapter` since it is a class, like `BaseAdapter`

Comment: is your context Aplication context?For a Dialog you have to use Activity's instance not application context.

Comment: @rogerthatcode yes, line number 115 in my customadapter

Comment: @devcelebi i sent context from list.setAdapter(new customadapter(oslist,getApplicationContext())); at registeritem.java 
i think my context already true

Comment: what is that line? i am asking !?.

Comment: @rogerthatcode just want to show the image into the showdialog.

Comment: @Shubham thank you . bug fixed ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an `interface`:

```
public interface OnDeleteListener {
    public void onDelete(String message);
}
```

When you are initializing `customadapter` send `OnDeleteListener` as a parameter:

```
private OnDeleteListener mListener;
public customadapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist,Context context, OnDeleteListener mListener) {  
    this.context = context;
    this.oslist = oslist;
    this.mListener = mListener;
}
```

then on `delete button click` check for `listener` to whether activate it or not:

```
 btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //I want show YES NO dialog here
            if(mListener != null)
              mListener.onDelete("The message you want to show");
        }
    });
```

and finally `initialize` adapter in your `activity/fragment` and on `listener invoke` show `Dialog`:

```
customadaper mAdapter = new customadapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist,Context context, new OnDeleteListener(){
   @Override
   public void onDelete(String msg){
    //Show your dialog here
    //msg - you can send any parameter or none of them through interface just as an example i send a message to show
    showDialog(msg);
}
});
```

You can create a *seperate function for code clearance* and call it whenever you want to use

**(also notice that, to create a `custom dialog` you have to `inflate` it {probably thats why you are getting an error})**:

```
private void showDialog(String message){
// set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
inflater = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_dialog, null, false);
TextView text = (TextView) inflater.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText(message);
ImageView image = (ImageView) inflater.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); //line 115

AlertDialog.Builder mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
             mDialogBuilder.setView(viewFilterDialog);
             mDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
mDialogBuilder.setTitle(mRes.getString(R.string.dialog_title_filter));
             ...

final AlertDialog mAlertDialog = mDialogBuilder.create();
mAlertDialog.show();
```

**note:** I have hardcoded this answer so any `syntax error` can occur

Answer (score 1):

try this code.For a Dialog you have to use Activity's instance not application context.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(youractivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
```

Answer (score 0):

first pass the activity like this.

```
list.setAdapter(new customadapter(oslist,getApplicationContext(),registerItem.this));
```

then get the parent activity like this..

```
private Activity parentActivity;
    private Button btnDelete;
    private Button btnEdit;

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;

    public customadapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist,Context context, Activity parentactivity) {  
        System.out.println("skdjfhksdfjskfjhsdkjfh");
        this.context = context;
        this.oslist = oslist;
        this.parentActivity = parentactivity;

    }
```

and set dialog builder like this..

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(parentActivity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in activity. For Adapter code, add some tags to your button to identify which button is pressed. You can also set position as a tag.

```
Button btnEdit = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
Button btnDelete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

btnEdit.setTag(oslist.get(position).get("id"),R.id.varId);
btnDelete .setTag(oslist.get(position).get("id"),R.id.varId);
```

You can add this in xml for your custom dialog.
    android:onclick="deleteMethod"

Write your method in activity like this :

```
public void deleteMethod(View v)
{
// Get your id or position for which delete button was pressed
 String id=v.getTag().toString();

 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("Title")
.setMessage("Do you really want to delete ?")
.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Deleting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// You know which item to delete from id / position. delete here.
    }})
 .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a easy way to do this, in my case i have followed this code. 
write a method `alertMessage()` and call this inside your button listener code

```
btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //I want show YES NO dialog here
              alertMessage();
        }
    }); 



public void alertMessage() { 
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
      switch (which) { 
         case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE: // Yes button clicked 
            Toast.makeText(AlertDialogActivity.this, "Yes Clicked",
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
             // set your own logic for removal item from listview      
             break; 

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE: // No button clicked // do nothing 
             Toast.makeText(AlertDialogActivity.this, "No Clicked", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
             break; 
          } 
        } 
    }; 

   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
   builder.setMessage("Are you sure?") 
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener) 
           .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show(); 
}
```

dialog will dismiss itself after user click "YES" or "NO" button. There is nothing you need to do