# What is the best way to implement contents and comments in One scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement the below image in android ,

I have used Relative Layout to display content and Recycler view to display comments but I want both under one scroll while my problem is recycler view is creating another scroll.

I also thought to add a layout dynamically but in that every layout I have  to implement click listener for every child , which is not good for performance

What could be the best way to implement it

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: You can make a `ListView` and add Image as a `header` or include it in a row

Comment: Will implement and will let you know , Your idea looks cool thanks for pointing me into right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `ListView` where row contains `Comments` part and add `Image` as a `Header` of that `ListView`.

The other way is to create a `Custom Adapter` and include `Image` and `Comments` as a **single row** of a `ListView`

For *implementing a `click event` on each item* you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118595/showdialog-in-button-listview-adapter/30119715#30119715)

Comment: Thanks I will implement it , and will accept answer

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `ListView` with custom elements in it (that look like the comments on the picture) instead of the `RecyclerView`